# Why is $|\lambda u|=|\lambda||u|$

Tags: linear-algebra

My text book in linear algebra - out of the blue - claims that:

$|\lambda u|=|\lambda||u|$

Where u is a vector and $\lambda$ is a constant.

I would understand if || were used to denote absolute numbers, but in this book, || is used to denote length (so the dot product of the vector v with itself is written as $|v|^2$)

I'm positively dumbfounded. How do I prove this and why would av scalar like $\lambda$ even have a length in the first place?

EDIT:

This is used in a later section to prove that the projection of v on u equals:

$$|\frac{u \cdotp v}{|u|^2}u|=\frac{|u \cdotp v|}{|u|^2}|u|=\frac{|u \cdotp v|}{|u|}$$ so it definitly seems they're referring to lengths, and not absolute numbers. Otherwise I can't really see that working.

Comment: $$\lvert \lambda \vec{u} \rvert = \sqrt{(\lambda u_{1})^{2}+(\lambda u_{2})^{2}+...} = \sqrt{\lambda^{2}} \sqrt{u_{1}^{2}+u_{2}^{2}+...} = \lvert \lambda \rvert \lvert \vec{u} \rvert$$ As you can see, $\lambda$ _does not_ have a length.

Comment: $|\lambda v|=|\lambda|\cdot |v|$ is part of the _definition_ of a norm. If this property is not satisfied then your operation doesn't deserve the notation $|\phantom v|$.

Comment: $|\lambda|$ is the absolute value of $\lambda$ and $|u|$ is the length of $u$. $\sqrt{\lambda u\cdot\lambda u}=|\lambda|\sqrt{u^2}$.

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that the $|\cdot|$ around $u$ and the $|\cdot|$ around $\lambda$ are different. The $|\cdot|$ around $u$ is to denote the standard Euclidean length, while the $|\cdot|$ around $\lambda$ is the absolute value function on $\Bbb{R}$ (which is actually the Euclidean length on the vector space $\Bbb{R}$). That's why, when referring to lengths, authors often prefer $\|\cdot\|$ instead of $|\cdot|$, to differentiate between scalar absolute values and vector lengths.

Comment: So the argument is that since the length of a vector in three dimensions is the square root of $x^2 +y^2+z^2$ and the length of a vector in two dimensions is the square root of $x^2+y^2$, the "length" of a vector in one dimension must be simply the square root of $x^2$?

Comment: If you want, but in the $1D$ case we use to say *absolute value*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may know about the dot product that $(\lambda u)\cdot (\mu v)=\lambda\mu (u\cdot v)$.
Hence
$$ |\lambda u|=\sqrt{\lambda u\cdot \lambda u)}=\sqrt{\lambda ^2 (u\cdot u)}=|\lambda|\sqrt{u\cdot u}=|\lambda|\,|u|.$$

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this makes it clear: $|\lambda u|_V=|\lambda|_{\mathbb R}\,|u|_V$.

It reads: the length of $\lambda u$ in the vector space $V$ is the product to the absolute value of $\lambda$ in $\mathbb R$ by the length of $u$ in $V$.

Using subscripts as above sometimes helps to make sense of what is going on.
For instance, if $T:V\to W$ is a linear transformation and $v_1,v_2 \in V$, then
$$
T(v_1+ v_2) = T(v_1) + T(v_2) 
$$
actually means
$$
T(v_1+_V v_2) = T(v_1) +_W T(v_2) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the definition of an inner product $\langle \;,\; \rangle$ on a complex vector space $V$ that

- $\langle \lambda v, w\rangle = \lambda\langle v, w\rangle,$ and
- $\langle v, \lambda w\rangle = \bar{\lambda}\langle v, w\rangle,$

for all $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ and $v, w \in V$. (As usual, $\bar{\lambda}$ is the complex conjugate of $\lambda$.)

After this, a norm is defined as
$$\|v\| = \sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle}.$$
This then gives us

\begin{align}
\|\lambda v\| &= \sqrt{\langle \lambda v, \lambda v\rangle}\\
&= \sqrt{\lambda\langle v, \lambda v\rangle}\\
&= \sqrt{\lambda\bar{\lambda}\langle v, v\rangle}\\
&= \sqrt{|\lambda|^2\langle v, v\rangle}\\
&= |\lambda|\sqrt{\langle v, v\rangle}\\
&= |\lambda|\|v\|.
\end{align}

---

In case you're working over $\Bbb R$, you just have $\lambda$ everywhere instead of $\bar{\lambda}$.